# How does the predicate 'repeat' create infinite choice points in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I do not understand how the predicate `repeat` evaluates to be true at all times and create infinite choice points. For example, when I call:

`:- repeat, reset, do(task,job).`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work all at once, but bit by bit. As if defined by the following two clauses:

```
 repeat.
 repeat :- repeat.
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer is only made better by the fact that your name is *repeat*